# vue.runtime.common.js: "Cannot read property '_transitionClasses' of undefined" when this.errors is not used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vee-validate, vue-test-utils

I have this strange error when I'm running a test on a component that's using [vee-validate](https://github.com/baianat/vee-validate). What's even weirder is that **it doesn't happen when I actually use `this.errors` in that component** (even putting `console.log(this.errors)` is making it disappear).

Test code:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { renderToString } from '@vue/server-test-utils';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import VeeValidateConfig from '@/vee-validate-config';
Vue.use(VeeValidate, VeeValidateConfig);
import FolderSelect from '@/components/FolderSelect';

describe('FolderSelect', () => {
let propsData, wrapperDeep;

beforeEach(() => {
    wrapperDeep = mount(FolderSelect);
});

it('renders select box if option "existing folder" is selected', () => {
    // this code is forcing component to use vee-validate:
    wrapperDeep.setData({folder: 'existing'}); 
});
```

Output from `yarn test:unit`:

> ```
> [Vue warn]: Error in directive validate bind hook: 
> "TypeError: Cannot read property '_transitionClasses' of undefined"
> ```

It's coming from `node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js`, line 1739 and 589.

After I add to tested component:

```
created () {
    console.log(this.errors);
},
```

The error is gone! Why the error appears otherwise? Is Vue clearing vee-validate if it's not used? (`this.errors` is an ErrorBag added by vee-validate). Doesn't help if I add `{{ errors }}` to the template, though.

I'm injecting vee-validate like this:

```
export default {
    inject: ['$validator'],
    (...)
```

Comment: Try this:
import { TransitionGroupStub } from '@vue/test-utils'
Vue.component('transition-group', TransitionGroupStub)

Comment: @Aldarund no difference :(

Comment: What about vue test util version? Anything higher than beta12 wont work

Comment: 1.0.0-beta.20, but from what I [read](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/components/transitiongroupstub/) it should use TransitionGroupStub and TransitionStub by default

Comment: beta20 wont work with vee validate. And with a lot of other libs too like vuetify. Beta 12 is a higher version that work with them

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/532 - because of this

Comment: @Aldarund works after downgrading to beta.12, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem try adding `{sync: false}` after mounting the component

```
beforeEach(() => {
  wrapperDeep = mount(FolderSelect,{sync: false});
});
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

We hit this at work with `@vue/test-utils@1.0.0-beta.25`, and it got resolved by updating to `@vue/test-utils@1.0.0-beta.29`, without using `sync: false`.